# How do I retrieve the images which doesn't have 'img' as the tag from an html document?

Tags: python, html, image, beautifulsoup, findall

I have a html file from which I want to extract all the images.
I am using beautiful soup to extract all the images,
EX : a piece of my code,

```
html = urlopen(slide_urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    for res in soup.findAll('img'):
        print(res.get('src'))
```

This code is giving me all the images with tags as 'img' but there are a lot of images which this function is not able to extract.
Can somebody help me here to deal with these kind of tags. For reference click on the link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/olFjx.png

Comment: This isn't an HTML <img> tag, but an image inside SVG, this is why you are not capturing it.

Comment: Oh yes, how do I retrieve these kind of images from python?

Comment: Can you give an example of a page you're scraping?